# Error The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I am trying to run a PowerShell script from a windows batch file. This is a SharePoint related script that uses `Import-SPData`.

This works without any issue when using `USERA`'s login. However, if I try to run the same batch file from `USERB`'s login, I get the error below:

```
c:\PS>ExecMyPowershellScript.bat

c:\PS>C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -psconsolefile "
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\P
OWERSHELL\Registration\psconsole.psc1" -command "c:\ps\MyPSScript.ps1"
```

> The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are
>   not registered.
>
> Import-SPData : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local
>   farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have
>   the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying
>   again.

```
At C:\ps\Run_MyPSScript.ps1:5 char:18
```

`USERB` has permissions to run the `bat` and the `ps1` files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are assuming, the error is related to permission to either the bat or the powershell file.

The error you get comes from a SP cmdlet, so you have successfully opened the bat file and successfully run the powershell script.
Which then throws an error. UserB has not the apropriate rights to the farm. Hence the error:

> ...and that you have the appropriate permissions to access the
>   database before trying again.

Compare the permissions from UserA and UserB on the farm and the database.

Or you could use a sledgehammer and log into UserA to run the following powershell script:

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase | Where {$_.Name -eq "SharePoint_ConfigDB"}
Add-SPShellAdmin "domain\UserB" -database $db
```

Comment: Thanks. My SharePoint config database name was SharePoint_Config_<random_letters_and_numbers> so I used `$dbs = Get-SPDatabase; foreach($d in $dbs) {If($d.name.contains("SharePoint_Config")){Add-SPShellAdmin "domain\USERB" -database $d}}`

Comment: Use `$dbs = Get-SPDatabase | Where {$_.Name -like "SharePoint_Config*" };` instead to find the target db.

Comment: I got this problem due to PowerShell version **[The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered/)**